# To get maximum 5 comma separated values at a time

Tags: python, mongodb, api, generator

How can I dynamically add values in an API's path?

I am extracting some values from an API json response, like this-

```
values = ['MP55', 'MP50', 'MP51', 'MP54', 'MP58', 'MP59', 'MP60', 'MP60', 'MP61', 'MP62', 'MP50', 'MP58', 'MP65']
type(values) = <class 'list'>
```

Now, I need to use maximum 5 values from this list to an API endpoint dynamically, and repeat in the same way to an API endpoint like this-

```
API - www.google.com/{you can provide 5 comma separated values here)}
```

like this

```
API - www.google.com/MP55, MP50, MP51, MP54, MP58, MP59
```

and after that the next 5 values, like

```
API - www.google.com/MP59, MP60, MP60, MP61, MP62
```

and so on... I tried to use '.join' to make it in the required format

```
new_values = ','.join(values)
output - MP55, MP50, MP51, MP54, MP58, MP59
<class 'str'>
```

Here I am getting a lot of data, and I want when I run the API this 'new_values' automatically adds data in the format of chunks of 5 elements in the API as I mentioned above. API gets the value automatically so that I can save the values in mongo db collection.

Comment: Use a slice like `values[:5]`.

Comment: Naïve slicing would fail if there's fewer than 5 values

Comment: See `grouper()` function at https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

Comment: @NikolajŠ. No, it won't fail with fewer than 5 values. Something like `[1, 2, 3][:5]` will work.

Comment: @NikolajŠ. slicing should work. What do you mean by fail? `','.join(values[:5])` should get maximum 5 items.

Comment: Like this, I tried.
API = f'https://google.com/{string_cdets[:5]}'

But it is slicing the first param value in the api.

Comment: @bekirbakar ','.join(values[:5]) is fine. It is giving me only first five values, but I want all the other values as well in the group of 5 so that these values can also be passed in the API in the next iteration, and so on.

Comment: I see your point. I think you can use `[values[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(values), 5)]` comprehension to iterate over it. If you expect too many values I suggest you use a generator.

Comment: @bekirbakar Can you please help me to use a generator for too many values ?

Comment: This is a closed discussion, so I can't post an answer here. However, I created a simple gist for you, feel free to leave a comment: https://gist.github.com/bekirbakar/11761c6601d813f13d75849ab1a1c37d

Comment: @bekirbakar print(f'First pack: {next(get_packs(sample_data))}')
print(f'Second pack: {next(get_packs(sample_data))}') is only printing same first five values. However we want to print next five values

Comment: Ohh I realized that I made a mistake: creating a new generator every time. See the updated, corrected code in the gist.